# Netty Http Client profiling. How to calculate time of server response?

Tags: asynchronous, events, netty, nio, timing

I wonder, how can I correctly calculate pure time of server response? Because if I will just wrap call of `HttpClient` with `System.currentTimeMillis` I will include time of adding event to EventLoop, waiting for processing and etc.

I know that I can do it more granular using `ChannelHandlers`, but can I use something at lower level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it in a ChannelHandler is the correct way to do something like this in netty.